# Is there a library for checking if css rules are written in a certain format?

Tags: css, string-parsing

In my project, I have this convention of writing my css files like

```
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER <sub css rules...> {

}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER <sub css rules...> {

}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER <sub css rules...> {

}
etc...
```

So in the css file, I want to ensure that all the rules (including ones in media query) start with `.some_name_APP_CONTAINER` (is a class), and the substring `some_name` can be whatever class name but should be the same for all rules in the css file. So this is valid for example:

```
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER .table {

}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER div {

}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER div:hover {

}
```

and this is not valid

```
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER .table {

}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER div {

}
div:hover {

}
```

So this is mainly for maintenance reasons, so that everything gets encapsulated under the class `some_name_APP_CONTAINER`. Is there some library anyone uses for validation of css rules?

Also I prefer node.js library as that would work best.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS pre-processor to help you do that. Although they wouldn't parse the CSS to ensure the encapsulation you're looking for, they would make it really easy to implement such a structure and double check.

The two most popular are [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

CSS pre-processors allow you to nest your selectors. To *"namespace"* selectors you could do the following.

```css
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER {
    table {}
    div {}
    div:hover {}
}
```

Once the pre-processor compiles the above pseudo CSS you'll get the results you're looking for.

```css
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER table {}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER div {}
.some_name_APP_CONTAINER div:hover {}
```

Ensuring the results you want could be as simple as seeing if all the selectors in a file reside with the `.some_name_APP_CONTAINER` block/selector.